# How to disable login button on a dynamically rendered form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am working on a login form where each input is created dynamically as a field.
This is my Login.js file:

```
   import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import{ Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import FIELDS from './loginFields';
import LoginField from './LoginField'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions'

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
            this.state={
               username: '',
               password: ''
            };
        };

    handleChange = (e)=>{
            this.setState({username: e.target.value, password: e.target.value});
             };
    
    renderFields(){
        return _.map(FIELDS, ({ label, name, type })=> {
            return <Field onChange={this.handleChange} className='purple-text' key={name} component={ LoginField } type={type} label={label} name={name} />
        });
    };

    render(){
        const { username, password } = this.state;
        const isEnabled = username.length > 0 && password.lenth>7;
        return (
            <div className='valign-wrapper row login-box' style={{marginTop:'100px'}}>
                <div className='col card hoverable s10 pull-s1 m6 pull-m3 l4 pull-l4'>
                    <form method='POST' action='/api/login'>
                         <div className = 'card-content'>
                             <span className='card-title purple-text' style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Login<a href='/register'> Not a member? sign up!</a></span>
                             <div className='center-align row'>
                                <li key='google' style={{marginLeft: '30px'}} className='col m6 center-align white-text darken-3'><a className='white-text' href='/auth/google'><img alt="" src="https://img.icons8.com/cute-clipart/64/000000/google-logo.png"/></a></li>
                                <li key='facebook' className='col  center-align white-text darken-3'><a className='white-text' href='/auth/facebook'><img alt = "" src="https://img.icons8.com/cute-clipart/64/000000/facebook-new.png"/></a></li>
                             </div>
                                <div className='row input-field col s12'>
                                 {this.renderFields()}
                                <Link to='/' className='purple btn-flat left white-text'>Back</Link>
                                <button disabled={!isEnabled} type='submit' className='purple btn-flat right white-text'>Login
                                 <i className='material-icons right'>done</i>
                                </button>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

function validate(values){
    const errors = {};

    _.each(FIELDS, ({name})=>{
        if(!values[name]){
            errors[name] = 'You must enter a value!'
        } 
    });
    return errors;
    
};

const form =  reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: 'LoginForm'
});


export default connect(null, actions)(form(LoginForm));
```

Here is loginFields.js

```
export default

[
    { label: 'Username', name: 'username', type: 'text'},
    { label: 'Password', name: 'password', type: 'password'}
];
```

and here is LoginField.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ input, label, type, meta })=>{

    return(
        <div>
            <label className='purple-text'>{label}</label>
            <input {...input} type={type} style= {{marginBottom: '5px'}}/>
            <div className = "red-text" style={{ marginBottom: '20px'}}>
                {meta.touched && meta.error}
            </div>
        </div>
            
    );
};
```

I am having trouble properly setting onChange and my constructor to disable the login button until all fields are filled.  I have been able to disable the button until a single input has started to be filled in, not disabled at all, and not enabled at all. but have not been able to achieve the desired outcome.

I have tried using lodash to map over each field grabbing values by the input name property, and moving functions around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if i can provide any more information for this question please let me know.

Comment: Just noticed a typo in the second line in the render function of LoginForm -- `const isEnabled = username.length > 0 && password.lenth>7;`  **length**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial problem I see is the onChange function will update state for both password and username whenever either of them is changed. The function takes the event and does not distinguish as to which input is the target. You can pass an additional parameter from the Field that includes the field name, or you can check the target's id or something so you know which input's state should be updated.

In LoginForm

```
 handleChange = (e, name)=>{
    this.setState({[name]: e.target.value});
             };
```

You also need to pass the onChange callback down to the actual input in LoginField.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ name, label, type, meta, onChange, ...props })=>{

    return(
        <div>
            <label className='purple-text'>{label}</label>
            <input onChange={(e) => onChange(e, name)} {...props} type={type} style= {{marginBottom: '5px'}}/>
            <div className = "red-text" style={{ marginBottom: '20px'}}>
                {meta.touched && meta.error}
            </div>
        </div>
            
    );
};
```

Here's a codeSandbox.

[image: Edit jolly-yalow-z77es]

Comment: have you tried this? button is staying disabled throughout the form regardless of the state of the inputs

Comment: In addition to the 'length' typo I mentioned in a separate comment, I just noticed in LoginField.js you are destructuring out an "input" prop that is undefined. I assumed it had the name in it, but name is passed in separately. I've updated the answer now. I tried it in codesandbox and it works.

Comment: i'm not sure why, but when i change {...input} to {...props} i get an error thrown "onChange is not a function" for every touched event. The only difference i'm seeing between the working sandbox code and mine at this point is the call to connect actions at the bottom of Login.js

Comment: i found it.  <Field> needed to reference <LoginField> instead.  thanks for your help!

Comment: this worked, but replacing <Field> component took away the meta props that come with it preventing my validation function to run properly.   after tons of digging I finally found documentation.  <Field> in redux form has a built in prop called {invalid} which checks against the validate function.   instead of messing with state all i had to do was add const {invalid} = this.props; inside the  render method, then <button disabled={invalid}>

Answer (score 2):

just adding this as an answer in case anyone else comes across this issue.

after tons of digging I finally found documentation.  in redux form has a built in prop called {invalid} which checks against the validate function. instead of messing with state all i had to do was add

```
  const {invalid} = this.props;
```

inside the render method. constructor and handle change and onChange were no longer necessary..   then.

```
  <button disabled={invalid}>
```